# How to update lots of rows with out locking table in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a job which is updating a table for 20 minutes and at these moments I can't update any row of it naturally.

Is there a way or method for to do this ?

The job can be more longer but I have to continue to update table.

On the other hand the job should rollback if it has got error during job.

Thanks..

Comment: FWIW, see [Row Versioning-based Isolation Levels in the Database Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177404(v=sql.105).aspx) (and related links). For when to use: "Reader/writer blocking occurs to the point that concurrency benefits outweigh increased overhead of creating and managing row versions." Note that it's about *not blocking* between transactions (i.e. less than SERIALIZABLE); not necessarily about overall performance ..

Comment: Which table hint is correct for this situation. I want to be able to update a row while it is updating hole table ?

Comment: You should not do that. If the job should be able to roll back you're going to get an awful mess if you move to a more lenient lock strategy (ie. you'll lose all your transactional integrity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the job into separate transactions. The way locks work in a professional DBMS like SQL Server is that they escalate to higher levels as they are required. Once a query has hit a lot of pages it's only natural that it's updated to a read-only table lock. The only way to circumvent this while keeping transactional integrity is to split it up in smaller jobs.

Comment: Do you have a link or a good search term where one could learn more about how to do what you suggest?

Comment: About splitting up a large job into smaller jobs? Erm no?

Answer (score 0):

As Niels has pointed out you should attempt to update the table in batches explicitly committing each batch within a transaction. If you are creating enough locks to warrant a table lock then the chances are you have also ballooned your transaction log. Its probably worth checking and shrinking down to a more reasonable size if necessary.

Alternatively you could try enabling Trace flags 1224 or 1211 which "Disables lock escalation based on the number of locks" - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188396.aspx